# export friends phones, emails and skype from facebook

Tags: php, regex, facebook, contacts

As facebook doesn't allow us to export our friends contact details, I want to do it manually. But as I have more that 500 contacts, I need to automate it a bit. This is what I do:

1) First I used DownThemAll firefox addon on https://www.facebook.com/friends to get links to all my friends profiles.

2) In excel I altered those urls adding /about (or &sk=about for those who don't have username) at the end of each link

3) Using DownThemAll I downloaded all "about" pages of my friends.

4) I merged all files into one using this windows command:

```
copy *.* merged.txt
```

5) In merged.txt file I change each double quote sign " into \" to use it in php file later as variable

6) This is the step I need your help. I want to parse this huge merged file into nice csv. I thought about using regular expressions in php.

My idea is to use code like this:

```
<?php
$content="here I paste everything from merged.txt";     
$regex_pattern = "this is what I need from you";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$content,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

I checked the code of facebook about page and parts I'm interested in can be matched like this:

-each new record start with <html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js"> and finishes with </html>

-name can be taken from the only  element having class="_8_2"

```
<a class="_8_2">name</a>
```

-telephone can be taken from the only span that has dir="ltr"

```
<span dir="ltr">123456789</span>
```

-email is the only mailto link

```
<a href="mailto:abc@abc.com">
```

-skype is the only callto link

```
<a href="callto:skypelogin" class="uiLinkDark">
```

Please remember that some users have only email or only telephone on their about page. So the regular expression has to catch also those cases.

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

BTW, I know there is easier way exporting contacts to yahoo and then printing them. But please don't suggest it, as it doesn't export phone numbers.

Comment: It seems that you've done it all already, but for future reference, [scraping Facebook is against their Terms of Service.](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php)

Comment: Do _name_, _telephone_, _email_ and _skype_, if present, always occur in this order?